# Default Animations is not playing again when the object is set inactive and made active again

Tags: unity

in my game I have a default animation added through animator. The default Animation is now stops working after playing once. In a non looped Animation clip, When the Object is disabled by setting it's SetActive false, then the default animation doesn't play upon reactivating the object. See the following package. When you open it in Unity 5.5 then Animation play fine but in Unity 5.6 Default animation plays only once

[File To download](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/attachments/91578-test.zip)

Comment: I have the same situation. Everything worked fine in 5.5 but after the update to 5.6 animations connected to the 'entry' state stopped working.

Comment: it's fixed in 5.6.0p1 and p2 
that was a bug in Unity Editor.